# Перевод слова "takeaway"

Tags: перевод

Есть ли аналоги слова "Takeaway" в русском языке? Контекст такой:

> I've read a book. Here are my takeaways.

Вопрос не в переводе фразы в целом, а в том, есть ли аналогичные слова или короткие фразы в русском.

Кроме "основные мысли" мне ничего не приходит на ум, но даже это отражает значение не точно. Ведь это не основные мысли, а то, что было важно в книге именно для меня -- то, что я из неё **вынес**.

Comment: Из 2 значения в ODO (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/takeaway) - A key fact, point, or idea to be remembered, typically one emerging from a discussion or meeting. Merriam webster (уже 1 значение - a conclusion to be made based on presented facts or information : a main point or key message to be learned or understood from something experienced or observed ). Основные мысли - подходит. И подобные варианты: основная идея, мысль, ключевые идеи и т.п. Если одно слово, то иногда может подойти "суть" (только в некотором контексте), но это не точный аналог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Таковы её уроки

или

> Вот такие уроки я извлёк
>
> Вот какие уроки я (для себя) извлёк/вынес

но это всё равно громоздко по сравнению с английским

Comment: английский гораздо гибче русского, ему не нужно ничего морфологически синтезировать, бери слово и используй как любую часть речи (ну или почти как любую) или сочетай как хочешь, потому в русском часто не находится слова в соответствующем грамматическом классе и ёмкие слова английского приходится переводить на русский целыми конструкциями или описательно, или приблизительно, чтобы не впадать в словотворчество

Comment: "Вот что я вынес". Русский язык тоже достаточно гибок, просто эта гибкость гораздо менее допускается в "возвышенные" стили (официально-деловой, научно-публицистический), в отличие от английского.

Comment: To illustrate your point, В Oxford dictionary [takeaway](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/takeaway) есть пример в смысле "урок" (‘The takeaway lesson for me, which I had already learned much earlier in life, is the importance of admitting mistakes.’). Это одно из возможных значений. Также там много других примеров, в основном, в смысле "key points, key ideas, etc."

Comment: Да, к сожалению, получается, что самый точный и короткий перевод это "урок, который я извлёк".

Comment: @Cubius Возможно. Хотя я еще раз всмотрелся в примеры [merriam webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/takeaway) и подумал, что могут быть "мои выводы". (Merriam webster дает _conclusion_ как одно из значений, например, _philosophical takeaway_ намекает на некоторые философские выводы). Без контекста (i read a book, here are the takeaways) судить трудно.

Answer (score 5):

Выводы? "Вот какие выводы я для себя сделал."

Comment: Или просто "Мои выводы"

Comment: i personally contemplated **выводы**, but discarded it as highly contextual, because **takeaway** doesn't necessarily have to be **выводы**, it could be just some **noteworthy points**, and in fact this goes to my **уроки** as well

Answer (score 4):

Изначально значение «на вынос», «с собой». Самое краткое будет «вот, что я узнал, вынес, **почерпнул**».

Comment: Спасибо за отличный ответ! Я думаю, из вопроса очевидно, что речь не о еде.

Comment: Это о происхождении слова,  не о вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

**Основные идеи, пункты, выжимка, конспект**

То, что конспект сделан вами, ясно из контекста; особо подчеркивать это необязательно.

> Я прочитал книгу. Вот основные идеи:
>
> 1.
> 2.
> 3.

Comment: Согласен, но не полностью. Более точный перевод был бы "Я прочитал книгу. Вот основные идеи, которые я вынес..." или "Вот очновные идеи, на которые следует обратить внимание".